# How do I convert jQuery code (click event that changes classes and text) to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a test website that I want to work on as a side project but I ran into a problem. I would like to convert the jQuery code to JavaScript so I can call it as a function and edit and write cookies. Here is a sample of my code:

```
$( ".inner-switch" ).on("click", function(){
    if( $( "body" ).hasClass( "dark" )) {
      $( "body" ).removeClass( "dark" );
      $( ".inner-switch" ).text( "OFF" );
    } else {
      $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
      $( ".inner-switch" ).text( "ON" );
    }
});
```

Here is my GitHub for the website: https://github.com/wrssmithjr04/wrssmithjr04.github.io
Thanks for the help!

Comment: "*I would like to convert the jQuery code to JavaScript so I can call it as a function and edit and write cookies*" you don't need this as plain JS code in order to make it into a function nor interact with cookies.

Comment: Then how do I call it from a function in the HTML document or within the same .js file.

Comment: The same way you call any other function - make one, put the desired code in it and call it. Is there a problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I will suggest to use `id` instead `class` and use `document.getElementById` and `document.querySelector` like so:

```js
const darkModeLink = document.getElementById('darkModeLink');

darkModeLink.addEventListener('click',
    () => {    
    const darkModeText = darkModeLink.querySelector('#darkModeText');
    const darkClass = "dark";
    if (document.body.classList.contains(darkClass)) {
      document.body.classList.remove(darkClass);
      darkModeText.innerText = "OFF";       
    } 
    else {
      document.body.classList.add(darkClass);
      darkModeText.innerText = "ON";       
    }
  }
);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0.9375rem;   
}
small {
    font-style: italic;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    align-self: center;
}
.switch {
    align-self: flex-end;
    color: #e6e6e6;
}
.inner-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    width: 3.125rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 0.1875rem;
    margin-left: 0.3125rem;
}
.dark,
.dark * {
    background-color: black;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<a style="float:right" id="darkModeLink" class="switch">   Dark mode:<span class="inner-switch" id="darkModeText">OFF</span></a>
```

Comment: Is there any pro to this compared to the one I marked as answer? My plan is to add a cookie that states the last theme option used so in page load the user preference would be restored.

Comment: Hi, well, I consider a pro, not use Jquery just plain Javascript, at least In this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

The function in your example is Anonymous. You just need to take it out and give it a name.

```
function YourFunction(){
    if( $( "body" ).hasClass( "dark" )) {
      $( "body" ).removeClass( "dark" );
      $( ".inner-switch" ).text( "OFF" );
    } else {
      $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
      $( ".inner-switch" ).text( "ON" );
    }
}
$( ".inner-switch" ).on("click", YourFunction);
```

With the above, `YourFunction` is called by your event as before but you call also call it yourself from the console or somewhere else in your code

Comment: So I can still use the <span> tag with this?

Comment: The code is essentially the same. If you could, then you still can.